# CSS grey box over image links

Tags: css, wordpress

I folks I have a problem which I solved on one page, but it has not fixed it on another...

There is a grey box that comes up over an image link which I am trying to get rid of.
It still shows up here:

http://1aproductions.ots-internet3.net/work/?cat=dramas

It does not show up here anymore: (On the three recent projects at the bottom)

http://1aproductions.ots-internet3.net

Here's the code I have used, which got rid of it on the homepage, but not on the other pages:

```
.pg-icon {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #252525;
 display: none;
background-color:transparent ;
background: none  ;
}

.pc-wrapper .icon-circle {

background-color:transparent ;
background: none ;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a **pc-wrapper** class on your dramas page, that's why the code in **.pc-wrapper .icon-circle** is ignored.

Your other pages seems to have a pg-items-wrapper class in common, so this code will make it work :

```
.pg-items-wrapper .icon-circle {
    background-color:transparent ;
    background: none ;
}
```